# To customise the UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uialertview

This is my code in a button action.I want to make my AlertView transparent to my page.How can it be done?

please help me to complete my Task......

```
    alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"qwwqreqrgvsdfhbsb" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss"otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];

    [alert show];

    UILabel *theTitle = [alert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
    [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UILabel *theBody = [ alert valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
    [theBody setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: What was the problem for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Background .

```
[alert setDimsBackground:NO];
```